# Which sequence ${a_n}$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is conditionally convergent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

Which sequence ${a_n}$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$  is conditionally convergent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ converges?
I tried with ${a_n}= \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ and it seems that it does. But I would like to know if there is another.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't mixing up sequences and series? If $\sum a_n$ converges, $a_n\to 0$; in particular, *as a sequence*, $a_n$ is absolutely convergent, since $a_n\to 0$ if and only if $|a_n|\to 0$ as well.

Comment: Yes, im sorry.I already corrected it.

Comment: do you need $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| = \infty$?

Comment: @user251257 Yes :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your favorite conditionally convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$, e.g. $b_n = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n}$. Then define $a_{2n} = b_n$ and $a_{2n - 1} = 0$. Then,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \in\mathbb R$$
and
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n| = \infty $$
and
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k a_k = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \in\mathbb R.$$

Comment: Thank you a lot. I couldn't have done it without your help

Answer (score 0):

Any alternating series that is convergent has an argument (excluding the $(-1)^n$ component) that is conditionally convergent. Examples of some are p-series with $p\geq1$ or $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$, and there are countless others.

Comment: be careful. The alternating harmonic series converges, the harmonic series does not converge.

Comment: I agree, but he wants to know about conditional convergence @user251257

Comment: I already tried the p series, but they are not conditionally convergent.

Comment: Why do you say that @JessFlo, all p-series with $p>1$ are absolutely convergent (and all absolutely convergent series are conditionally convergent) and the alternating harmonic series is convergent so they are indeed conditionally convergent.

Comment: @justaguy I need that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ diverges

Comment: Ohh lol, didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

Let $\zeta := e^{2 \pi i/3} = \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ be a primitive 3rd root of unity. Then $\xi :=-\zeta = \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} = e^{5\pi i/3}$ is a primitive 6th root of unity, and the partial sums

\begin{align*}
\zeta + \zeta^2+&...+\zeta^n \\
\xi +\xi^2 +&...+\xi^n \
\end{align*}

are both bounded for all $n \geq 0$ (by [the sum of a finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series)). Therefore, by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test),

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta^n}{n^s} \text{ and } \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\xi^n}{n^s} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\zeta^n}{n^s}$$

are both conditionally convergent for any $s$ with $0 < s \leq 1$. So $a_n = \frac{\zeta^n}{n^s}$ works.

If you want an example with terms in $\mathbb{R}$, just take the real part of the example above: $a_n = Re(\frac{\zeta^n}{n^s})$.